# Unicode-math and mathrm result in missing symbols

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

I've played around for a while and searched quite a bit but can't find a solution.
my code is the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hepnicenames}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}

\begin{document}

\section*{About this template}
\begin{equation}
  \mu + \mathrm{\mu} - γ + \mathrm{γ} + \Pmuon
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, when compiling with luatex the mathrm versions never get printed but are simply missing.

[image: lu]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I can confirm the behavior with my installation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

\mathrm is the wrong command, use \symrm

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hepnicenames}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}

\begin{document}

\section*{About this template}
\begin{equation}
  \mu + \symrm{\mu} - γ + \symrm{γ} + \Pmuon
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the super quick reply! 
Any insights into how I'd get the \Pmuon from the hepnicenames to work?

Comment: the sty is not adapted to unicode-math. Someone would have to rewrite the internal commands to use \sym-commands too.

Comment: Ok I guess I could actually work without that package for now.  For my understanding, Could you maybe add an explanation on what the difference is between mathrm and symrm? 
Looking at an old paper the above method seemed to work ~2 years ago for me.

Comment: \symrm will use math symbols from the math font, \mathrm switches to a text font.

Comment: For completeness, `\symup` works too.

Comment: Package option `mathrm=sym` will work as well. However I am not sure if doing so will break `\operatorname` kerning.